# android R.java behavior when a library project is added

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am using zxing library for barcode scanning in my application. So i have set zxing project as a library and adding that library to my project ( properties -> android -> add library )

After adding the library project when i build the code , i see that there are two R.java files created within my project.

One is under the path :gen\com\google\zxing\client\android

and the other : gen\myproject

The first one has all the resource variables from the library plus the resource variables in my project. The second one has resource variables only from my project.
When a new layout or resource variable is added its getting updated in both files

So my doubts are :
1. why there are two R.java files 
2. Is there a way i can stop generating the one with all library project variables

Because of this behaviour i ran in to very strange issues which was very difficult to debug.

In my zxing library there is a layout "capture" that will be set when we try to scan a barcode. Whenever i was adding any layout or any resource variable with name starting with letter "a" / "b"  my application was giving weird behaviours . And everything worked perfect when i just renamed the layout 
Later i found that it has something to do with the the id for "capture" in R.java file.
When i define a layout with letter starting a, it will be inserted in the R.java list before "capture" and thus the id for capture was changing. ( There is another R.java file in the actual zxing project which i had set as library. So seems like the id for capture in my R.java file and the zxing library R.java should be same )

Can you please explain what is really happening here

Answer (score 0):

I think you include the complete project...

If so delete that, and only import this files into your project:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fintegration%2Fandroid%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Thats all you need :)

Comment: I am doing in a different wher i first take zxing project, set it as library and then use that library in my project. Not using the integartor files. As explained in this link http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/#comment-233              Is this not the right way to do it ?

Comment: I did something like that a while ago. The user need to install your application and the additional zxing scanner. That are two apps from Google Play (Android Market)! So that code DO NOT include source code as a library to your source. It just open a other app and return the value (the barcode) from that app.

The problem with the example you gave me, is that you expect from users to download a second program.

I hope you understand my story, if you have questions just ask :)

Comment: With my case i generate the apk for my app and with that app user can do the scanning. No need to have zxing installed or no need to download anything else. It works perfect. My concern is i am trying to understand the code behaviour , how the R.java is getting picked up.

Comment: i see its the usual behaviour to have 2 R.java when a library project is added . I tetsed with some other projects and confirmed. But i am not clear how the resource files will be picked up.

Comment: I have started a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994940/android-r-java-mapping-to-resource-layouts-when-a-library-project-is-added